# How to extend doctrine entity in another bundle?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a gallery bundle, it's supposed to be reusable in other projects.
In this bundle I have these entities:

```
My\GalleryBundle\Entity\Album
My\GalleryBundle\Entity\Photo
My\GalleryBundle\Entity\AlbumPhotoAssociation
```

Both `Album` and `Photo` has one-to-many association to `AlbumPhotoAssociation`, because I need a `order` column in this many-to-many relation between album and photo.

They all have annotations

```
@ORM\Entity
@ORM\Table
```

so user of this bundle can have default tables and relationships out of box. and without `ORM\MappedSuperclass` because superclass can't have one-to-many relation.

===========

Now I include this bundle in my project and I want to override(extend) something of those entities, like:

- change table name
- add extra columns
- define project specific const, like `const STATUS_VERIFIED_BY_ADMIN = 5;` in `class Photo`

I've tried to have subclasses in my bundle extending from them, but I got this error

> Class \"My\MainBundle\Entity\Album\" sub class of
>   \"My\GalleryBundle\Entity\Album\" is not a valid entity or mapped
>   super class.

When I tried to persist my subclass or get the repository

```
$this->em->getRepository('MyMainBundle:Album');
// Or
$this->em->persist($album); // an instance of My\MainBundle\Album
```

I'm now stucked, have no idea how to do this properly. Or should I only define some traits in gallery bundle and define event entity class in my main bundle?

Comment: Did you found this one already? http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

Comment: @PiWi Yes this is what I said "This means that One-To-Many associations are not possible on a mapped superclass at all." And STI and CTI is also not fit my case

Comment: OK, missed that line. I would remove the One-To-Many in the mapped superclass en add that mapping in the child entity. If you need the mapping in both, you can also create a Model and extend both entities from the Model.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using mapped-superclass, and add the one-to-many relation in a EventListener.

```
<?php

namespace My\GalleryBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LoadClassMetadataEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo;

class MappingListener
{
    public function loadClassMetadata(LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $classMetadata = $eventArgs->getClassMetadata();

        if ('My\GalleryBundle\Entity\Album' === $classMetadata->reflClass) {
            $classMetadata->mapOneToMany(array(
                'fieldName' => 'albumPhotoAssociation',
                'targetEntity' => 'My\GalleryBundle\Entity\AlbumPhotoAssociation',
                'mappedBy' => 'album',
                'orphanRemoval' => true,
            ));
        }
        if ('My\GalleryBundle\Entity\Photo' === $classMetadata->reflClass) {
            $classMetadata->mapOneToMany(array(
                'fieldName' => 'albumPhotoAssociation',
                'targetEntity' => 'My\GalleryBundle\Entity\AlbumPhotoAssociation',
                'mappedBy' => 'photo',
                'orphanRemoval' => true,
            ));
        }

    }
}
```

Now, you must create a service:

```
services:
    acme_mapping_listener:
        class: My\GalleryBundle\EventListener\MappingListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: loadClassMetadata }
```

Comment: This sounds actually good. So - is this the recommended solution when I want to develop my system of bundles working together?